# Does "make install", by convention, updates the targets it installs?

Tags: linux, makefile

You usually invoke the following commands to build a `./configure`d product:

```
make
make install
```

Okay, the product is in the system now.  Then you change some source code files and invoke only `make install`.  The question is, does the conventional implementation of `install` target requires the executables to be recompiled, or just the old ones should be copied to the appropriate system path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whose *conventional* you like, of course.  Here's the [GNU convention](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html):

> **install**
>   Compile the program and copy the executables, libraries, and so on to the file names where they should reside for actual use.

And this seems like the sensible convention: having `make install` install out-of-date executables would mostly lead only to confusion.

Comment: And note that *this is a very bad thing*. When running `make install` as root a build program can often do stupid unexpected things like delete /dev/null.

Comment: Never seen that in my life.  @Zan: so your recommendation is not to run `make install` as root?  Don't know how well that is going to work...

Comment: No, my recommendation is to write make install scripts that don't automatically build.

Comment: Oh, and the /dev/null delete thing I have seen happen with gcc -o /dev/null. I don't know if current gcc does it still but it used to delete the old output file before writing the new one.

Answer (score 3):

`make` deals with this by design if your dependencies are correctly set up.

If ̀`make` build a binary named `helloworld`. You will probably write your `install` target so it copies this `helloworld` binary from your source directory to `/usr/bin`.

It means that the install target should depend on helloworld binary which also mean that if the binary `helloworld` is not up-to-date it will be recompiled. Thous when you type make install make implicitly call `make` (default target here).

Comment: eee .. I just figure out that your question is actually about what the install target should depend on right  ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a well-written makefile will have `install` depend on the executable being installed (or on `all`), so it will ensure that the executable is up-to-date before installing it.

There are several reasons for the split.  Conventionally, the default target is `all` and that doesn't install the files, only build them.  For developers, this means that they can build the sources in their working environment easily without affecting the rest of their system.  For end users, it means that they can run the build as a regular user, then only run `make install` as root.

It does mean that technically, the `make` stage of `make; make install` is redundant.